# What types of Macros/Syntax Extensions/Compiler Plugins are there?

Tags: macros, rust

I am very confused by the many terms used for several macro-like things in the Rust ecosystem. Could someone clarify what macros/syntax extensions/compiler plugins there are as well as explain the relationship between those terms?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right: it *is* confusing. Especially, because most of those features are unstable and change fairly often. But I'll try to summarize the current situation (*December 2016*).

---

[image: Venn-diagram showing compiler-plugins and syntax-extensions]

Let's start with the **Syntax Extension**: it's something that has to be "called" or annotated manually in order to have any effect. There are three kinds of syntax extensions, which differ in the way you annotate them:

- **function-like syntax extensions**: these are probably the most common syntax extensions, also called "macros". The syntax for invoking them is `foo!(…)` or (and this is pretty rare) `foo! some_ident (…)`, where `foo` is the macro's name. Note that the `()` parenthesis can be replaced by `[]` or `{}`. *Function-like syntax extensions* can be defined either as a "*macro by example*" or as a "*procedural macro*".
- **attribute-like syntax extensions**: these are invoked like `#[foo(…)]` where the parenthesis are not necessary and, again, `foo` is the name of the syntax extension. The item the attribute is belonging to can then be modified or extended by additional items (decorator).
- **custom derives**: most Rust-programmers have already used the `#[derive(…)]` attribute. Of course, `derive` itself can be seen as *attribute-like syntax extension*. But it can also be extended, which is then invoked like `#[derive(Foo)]`, where `Foo` is the name of the *custom derive*.

---

Most of these syntax extensions are also "**compiler plugins**". The only exception are *function-like syntax extensions* which are defined via "*macro by example*" (meaning `macro_rules!` syntax). *Macros by example* can be defined in your source code without writing a *compiler plugin* whatsoever.

But there are also **compiler plugins** that aren't *syntax extensions*. Those types of *compiler plugins* are linters or other plugins which run some code at some stage of the compiling process. They don't need to be invoked manually: once loaded, the compiler will call them at certain points during compilation.

All *compiler plugins* need to be loaded – either via `#![plugin(foo)]` at the crate-root or with the `-Zextra-plugins=too,bar` command line parameter – before they can have any effect!

*Compiler plugins* are currently unstable, therefore you need a nightly-compiler to use them. But the ["Macro 1.1"-RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1681-macros-1.1.md) will probably be stabilized soon, which means that a small subsets of *compiler plugins* can then be used with the stable compiler.

---

Useful links:

- [Documentation about registering *compiler plugins*](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/rustc_plugin/registry/struct.Registry.html)
- [Book Chapter about *compiler plugins*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/compiler-plugins.html)

Comment: Please let me know if I made any mistake! Since I've never written a compiler plugin, it was pretty difficult to get all this information. It's not unlikely that I made a mistake! Please tell me (or just edit, if it can be edited)!

Comment: `rustc` has the `-Zextra-plugins=too,bar` command line option to add plugins without annotating the code.

Comment: @llogiq Thanks! I added it to my answer.