# I can't find definition for `mock!`

Tags: macros, rust

I'm curious about [mocker](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers)'s macro `mock!`, so I cloned the project and try to find the definition. Unfortunately I checked every sentences include `macro_rules!` by full-text search and can't find it. Is there anyone who can tell me where the `mock!` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros defined by `macro_rules!` are called *macro by example*. These are the simplest, but not the only kinds of macros you can define in Rust! In particular, `mocker` uses unstable Rust features to register a more powerful kind of macro.

You can see the code for registering the macro [in `mockers_codegen/src/lib.rs`](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers/blob/1c07617b052d5548b829de80900aa4b44ca3c1de/mockers_codegen/src/lib.rs#L35):

```
pub fn register(reg: &mut rustc_plugin::Registry) {
    // ...
    reg.register_macro("mock", generate_mock);
    // ...
}
```

And the function "defining" the macro is [`generate_mock`](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers/blob/0d9c084d0c37369dbca16356d712044ec7ca2f82/mockers_codegen/src/lib.in.rs#L108-L130).

These kinds of macros work fundamentally different than `macro_rules!`. Explaining the details of all different kinds of macros and compiler plugins would be too much for this answer. You could take a look at [this (unfortunately slightly outdated) answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213128/2408867).